# Create symlinks to libraries in different folder during installation with CMake

Tags: cmake

In my project I'd need to install my libraries in `lib/`, and to create symlinks to them in `plugin/`. I'm currently doing it in this way:

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libMyLib.so ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/plugin/lib")
```

This works, but if I configure the cmake run with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/prefix1` and then I want to install just once in another folder by calling `cmake --install . --prefix /tmp/prefix2` then I get errors because the symlinks are created referring to the standard installation prefix, i.e. `/tmp/prefix2`.

So my question is: is there a way to create custom symlinks during installation taking into account the actual installation prefix?
Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Just guessing - would `install(CODE .... \${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} ..` work?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much @KamilCuk. If you take the time to write an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of expanding `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` on configuration side, expand it when it is executed:

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink \${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libMyLib.so \${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/plugin/lib)")
```